# Can Unity play Mechanical Golems when she gets to play a card outside of her turn?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

All Mechanical Golems in Unity's deck say the following:

> This card cannot be played during your play phase.

It's pretty clear that this means that during your turn, you cannot play a Mechanical Golem card as the card you play after resolving start of turn effects and before using a power (that's the Play Phase).

I presume that this means that you can't also play a Mechanical Golem card through something like Inspired Repair, which lets you play another card (since you would have played Inspired Repair, and resolved its effects, during your Play Phase).

But say that during another player's turn, you are given the opportunity to play a card. For instance, say that Fanatic is defeated and uses her "One player may play a card now" ability. Since it is not happening during Unity's Play Phase, could she play a Mechanical Golem straight from her hand and bypass the regular restriction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, she can play a mechanical golem outside of her play phase as if it was any other card. All that card is saying is you can't play it during the play phase and it does not mention not being able to play it like any other card.

> This card cannot be played during your play phase.

Take this card for instance

> Scrap Metal - "At the end of your turn, either take 1 Mechanical Golem from play back into your hand, or destroy this card.
>   At the start of your turn, you may play a card. If you do, destroy this card."

What that card lets you do after you take a mechanical golem from play in into your hand you can then play it during the start phase of your next turn allowing it to  return the play with full health. What this means is that you can play a mechanical golem during your turn as long as it is not the play phase. The start of turn, user a power, draw a card and end of turn steps (or during any other player/environment/villain turn) are perfectly legal to play a mechanical golem as long as you gain the ability to play a card during those steps.

Comment: This is also why characters like Omnitron X and Argent Adept that can put cards into play from Unity's deck, or give plays on other turns, work so well in conjunction with Unity -- anything that lets her more freely play bots makes her more awesome.  :)